# HTMLAgility pack C# unclosed colgroup tag

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, html-sanitizing

I have a string (HTML) being posted to server side and then it is validated using HTMLAgility pack. In the HTML there is an unclosed colgroup tag.

After sanitizing, the closing colgroup tag appears but right between closing "tbody" and "table" tag

BEFORE:

```html
<table width="3265" class="mce-item-table" style="width: 2452pt; border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

 <colgroup><col width="80" style="width: 60pt;">
 <col width="245" style="width: 184pt;" span="13"> <!-- MISSING COLGROUP tag-->
 <tbody><tr height="20" style="height: 15pt;">
  <td width="80" height="20" style="width: 60pt; height: 15pt; color: blue; text-decoration: underline; text-underline-style: single;"><span style="color: blue;">31109173</span></td>
  <td width="245" style="width: 184pt; font-family: Arial; font-size: 9pt;">31109173</td>
  <td width="245" align="right" style="width: 184pt; font-family: Arial; font-size: 9pt;">May 09,2017 9:54 AM</td>
  <td width="245" align="right" style="width: 184pt; font-family: Arial; font-size: 9pt;">May 08,2017 5:21 PM</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height="20" style="height: 15pt;">
  <td height="20" style="height: 15pt; color: blue; text-decoration: underline; text-underline-style: single;"><span style="color: blue;">30933775</span></td>
  <td style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 9pt;">30933775</td>
  <td align="right" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 9pt;">May 09,2017 9:50 AM</td>
  <td align="right" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 9pt;">Apr 28,2017 6:22 PM</td>
 </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

AFTER:

```html
<table width="3265" class="mce-item-table" style="width: 2452pt; border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

 <colgroup><col width="80" style="width: 60pt;">
 <col width="245" style="width: 184pt;" span="13">
 <tbody><tr height="20" style="height: 15pt;">
  <td width="80" height="20" style="width: 60pt; height: 15pt; color: blue; text-decoration: underline; text-underline-style: single;"><span style="color: blue;">31109173</span></td>
  <td width="245" style="width: 184pt; font-family: Arial; font-size: 9pt;">31109173</td>
  <td width="245" align="right" style="width: 184pt; font-family: Arial; font-size: 9pt;">May 09,2017 9:54 AM</td>
  <td width="245" align="right" style="width: 184pt; font-family: Arial; font-size: 9pt;">May 08,2017 5:21 PM</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height="20" style="height: 15pt;">
  <td height="20" style="height: 15pt; color: blue; text-decoration: underline; text-underline-style: single;"><span style="color: blue;">30933775</span></td>
  <td style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 9pt;">30933775</td>
  <td align="right" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 9pt;">May 09,2017 9:50 AM</td>
  <td align="right" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 9pt;">Apr 28,2017 6:22 PM</td>
 </tr>
</tbody></colgroup></table>

<!-- ^^ </colgroup> has appeared above-->
```

I tried setting "OptionFixNestedTags" flag to true. I still get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I tried various options from HTMLAgility pack and setting them true. This didn't work.

```
OptionFixNestedTags = true;
OptionAutoCloseOnEnd = true;
```

There is a nice Nuget package which sanitizes the html. The problem which I faced was tackled here -> [HtmlSanitizer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlSanitizer/)

Hope this helps.